# Zoom controls not rendering properly on the map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does anybody know why the zoom controls don't render properly on the map below?
The issue occurs in IE 10 and Chrome, it's fine in Firefox. Sometimes when I refresh the page the zoom controls render fine.

[image]

Comment: Are you using any framework? Bootstrap for example.

Comment: I am using the PrototypeJS framework

Comment: the css on your page conflicts with that on those images.

Comment: @geocodezip I thought that might be the case but the first time I go to that webpage the zoom controls don't render properly but when I refresh the page the controls render fine. It's quite random.

Comment: What I don't understand is that why sometimes the zoom controls render fine and sometimes they don't.

Comment: In IE 10 the zoom controls appear to render properly for like a second and then they disappear. Then I refresh the page and the zoom controls render fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by CloudFlare's Mirage 2 which automatically optimizes image loading through virtualized and lazy-loaded images.